# Azure Storage CloudQueue.AddMessage() timeout

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

### Background

I have a Azure Storage Queue for transferring messages between different micro services. Installed the `WindowsAzure.Storage` package (version 9.2.0) from Nuget.

This is how en-queue new message to queue done:

```
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(my_obj));
Queue.AddMessage(message);
```

### The problem

In 99.9% of calls, it working great. From time to time, I see the the function `Queue.AddMessage()` is being stuck for long period.

The code above is wrapped within an object that count the execution time. The wrapper is running by the Main thread and running the code above in different thread. If the execution is taking too long, the main thread abort the running thread. In my case, it running for 180 seconds and then the wrapper just kill the thread.This leads injecting `ThreadAbortException`:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 751
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.AddMessage(CloudQueueMessage message, Nullable`1 timeToLive, Nullable`1 initialVisibilityDelay, QueueRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs:line 1284
```

It not makes any sense to this code to run for 180 seconds (or more). It should be much faster.

### Questions:

I'm suspecting that this problem is because of HTTP timeout mechanism running at the back-end of the `WindowsAzure.Storage` nuget package.

1. What is the default HTTP request timeout that being used in the `AddMessage()` command? How to check?
2. How to change the default HTTP request timeout to different one?

Comment: If you perform addings to queue parallel, it may be caused by limit of numbers of request to one endpoint from client. Look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have the app.config system.net->connnectionManagment `<add address="*" maxconnection="9999999" />` that should give it high number of allowed requests. Not solving the issue.

Comment: Also single queue has rate limit: [2000 messages per second](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-queue-storage-limits)

Comment: I don't reach this for sure. Also, I don't find it reasonable to freeze on the `AddMessage` function for 180 seconds.

Comment: At this case, you can profile your application(for example, with the help of Visual Studio Performance Profiler). Also show us your code, may be you have logical mistake.

Comment: I did similar test, just with Stopwatch. Uploaded it to production. This code is running >10K times per day but being stack <3 times per day.

Comment: We can do nothing without your code